# Django query- 'not equal to' filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am writing a Django query to filter a list of teams which the user is a part of. 
(The Team and UserTeams models I am querying):

```
class Team(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    countryID = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)


class UserTeams(models.Model):
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teamID = models.ForeignKey(Team,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm struggling to make two queries:

**Query 1:**
The first query (`teamquery`) filters the Teams by checking if the `owner=request.user`, and I then display a list of these teams in my template.

**Query 2:** I then want to display a list of teams where the `UserTeams UserID = request.user` (`userteamquery`)

**Problem:**
Some teams are appearing in both query results. Is there a 'not equal' query I can use where it will exclude all UserTeams in the userteamquery where the teamID is a result of teamquery? so teamID=teamquery

```
@login_required
def teamsview(request):

 teamquery = Team.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
 userteamquery = UserTeams.objects.filter(userID=request.user)
 return render(request, 'teammanager/teams.html', {
    "teams": teamquery, "userteams": userteamquery})
```

Tried to exclude() (pretty sure this isn't even valid use)

```
userteamquery = 
UserTeams.objects.exclude(teamID=teamquery).filter(userID=request.user)
```

This didnt change anything at all in my output

Also tried ~Q but didnt change anything either:

```
userteamquery = UserTeams.objects.filter(Q(userID=request.user), 
~Q(teamID=teamquery))
```

*Edit - 
Added __in to my parameter, this works:

```
userteamquery = UserTeams.objects.filter(Q(userID=request.user), 
~Q(teamID__in=teamquery))
```

Comment: Did you try? userteamquery = UserTeams.objects.filter(userID!=request.user)

Comment: You can use either `exclude()` or `~Q()`.

Comment: @Alasdair I tried both of those but maybe i did it incorrectly, how exactly would i use each

Comment: @Alasdair, to be precise, it is valid Python (syntactically), it just does not work. It will pass `bool` value instead of specifying field value.

Comment: @kate Update your question with details, how did you use them

Comment: @soon added edits

Comment: @kate try to add `_in` to the parameter name: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: @soon yes it worked, thanks

Comment: @kate please add your working code as an answer to your question to help other users with similar issue